# addEventListener is not a function

Tags: javascript

hi i am trying to close the divs using the close click..
here is the code

```
var closeIcon=document.getElementsByClassName('.monique-close-icon');  

    function closeBigImgAndContainer()
{
    MoniqueDiv.style.display= "none";
    currentBigImageToDisplay.style.display="none";
};

closeIcon.addEventListener("click", closeBigImgAndContainer);
```

But in console there is an error 
**Uncaught TypeError: closeIcon.addEventListener is not a function(anonymous function) @ main.js:14**
Please tell me where i am doing it wrong...Thanks.

Comment: See this fiddle for a working example of what you're trying to do. http://jsfiddle.net/vhe17shd/

Answer (score 24):

`getElementsByClassName` returns an array of elements, `addEventListener` exists on elements.

The fix would be to iterate over the result set from getElementsByClassName and call addEventListener on each item:

```
var closeIcons=document.getElementsByClassName('.monique-close-icon');  

function closeBigImgAndContainer()
{
    MoniqueDiv.style.display= "none";
    currentBigImageToDisplay.style.display="none";
};

for (i = 0; i < closeIcons.length; i++) {
    closeIcons[i].addEventListener("click", closeBigImgAndContainer);
}
```

Comment: In addition to your answer, the selector is also wrong.

Comment: @Syadani I added and id and it worked. Thanks.,

Comment: Technically it returns a collection, which is array-like.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like the `closeIcon` variable has undefined value.
It is because [getElementsByClassName(..)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) method takes the `class` name as its parameter.

You can try to fix it as below:

```
var closeIcons = document.getElementsByClassName('monique-close-icon');
var i = closeIcons.length;
while (i--)
  closeIcons[i].addEventListener("click", closeBigImgAndContainer);
```

Also the method [getElementsByClassName(..)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/getElementsByClassName) returns a collection of nodes, not a single element. To assign an event listener we need to loop that collection and assign event to each DOM element in it.

Comment: You're right that the selector is wrong, but the issue is that you cannot call the addEventListener on a collection of elements.

Comment: What if he wanted to attach event handlers to all of the elements?

Comment: I believe he was attempting to add the same event listener to all the elements with one method, which is not possible, seeing as how the collection does not have a method with that name.

Answer (score 2):

Firstly, your selector is wrong. It should look like this:

```
var closeIcon = document.getElementsByClassName('monique-close-icon');
```

Then you need to append the event handlers as if you were dealing with an Array, as the .getElementsByClassName() method returns a collection of elements.

```
var closeIcon = document.getElementsByClassName('monique-close-icon'); 
function closeBigImgAndContainer(e)
{
    MoniqueDiv.style.display= "none";
    currentBigImageToDisplay.style.display="none";
};

for (var i = 0; i < closeIcon.length; i++) {
   closeIcon[i].addEventListener('click', closeBigImgAndContainer); 
}
```

Here's a working example:
http://jsfiddle.net/vhe17shd/